# R : library "parallel" necessary?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

i am sorry to ask again .
I am doing simulation study regarding combination factors of sample sizes,variances and different distribution.

Now, i am wondering do i need to include this

```
 library(parallel)
```

in the beginning of the code?

```
##########################################################################


#to evaluate the same R function on many different sets of data
library(parallel)

rm(list=ls())    # clean the workspace
nSims<-10000
alpha<-0.05

#set nrow =nsims because wan storing every p-value simulated 
#for gamma distribution with equal skewness
matrix2_equal  <-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)
matrix5_unequal<-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)
matrix8_mann   <-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)

# to ensure the reproducity of the result 
#here we declare the random seed generator
set.seed(1)

## Put the samples sizes into matrix then use a loop for sample sizes
 sample_sizes<-matrix(c(10,10,10,25,25,25,25,50,25,100,50,25,50,100,100,25,100,100),
 nrow=2)

#shape parameter for gamma distribution for equal skewness
#forty five cases for each skewness!!!!
sp1<-matrix(rep(c(16/9),each=45),ncol=1)

scp <- c(1,1.5,2,2.5,3)

##(use expand.grid)to create a data frame 
ss_scp<- expand.grid(sample_sizes[2,],scp)

#create a matrix combining the forty five cases of combination of sample sizes,shape and scale parameter
all <- cbind(rep(sample_sizes[1,], 5),ss_scp[,1],sp1,ss_scp[,2])

# name the column samples 1 and 2 and standard deviation
colnames(all) <- c("m","n","sp","scp")

#set empty vector of length no.of simulation(10000) to store p-value 
equal<-unequal<-mann<-c(rep(0,nrow(all)))

#set nrow =nsims because wan storing every p-value simulated 
#for gamma distribution with equal skewness
matrix2_equal  <-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)
matrix5_unequal<-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)
matrix8_mann   <-matrix(0,nrow=nSims,ncol=5)

    ##for the samples sizes into matrix then use a loop for sample sizes
     # this loop steps through the all_combine matrix
      for(ss in 1:nrow(all))  
      {
       #generate samples from the first column and second column
        m<-all[ss,1]
        n<-all[ss,2]   

           for (sim in 1:nSims)
           {
            #generate 2 random samples from gamma distribution with equal skewness
            gamma1<-rgamma(m,1.777778,scale=all[ss,4])
            gamma2<-rgamma(n,1.777778,scale=1)

            #extract p-value out and store every p-value into matrix
            p<-t.test(gamma1,gamma2,var.equal=TRUE)$p.value 
            q<-t.test(gamma1,gamma2,var.equal=FALSE)$p.value
            r<-wilcox.test(gamma1,gamma2)$p.value 

            matrix2_equal[sim,1]<- p   
            matrix5_unequal[sim,1]<- q 
            matrix8_mann[sim,1] <- r
        }
           ##store the result
          equal[ss]<- sum(matrix2_equal[,1]<alpha)
          unequal[ss]<-sum(matrix5_unequal[,1]<alpha)
          mann[ss]<- sum(matrix8_mann[,1]<alpha)
      }
```

Comment: will it have any difference with or without the "library(parallel)"?

Comment: If you don't use something, you don't need to load it. But f you have a performance-problem, trying to optimize your code might speed things up (for-loops can be notoriously slow in R)

Answer (score 4):

Remove the package parallel (`detach("package:parallel", unload=TRUE)`) and run your code without loading the package. If you get an error stating that function xy could not be found, you might need the package.
However, I do not see any line in your code that seems to require the parallel package.

Comment: Remove the 's', and call it a _package_ not a _library_.  Answer is otherwise spot-on.

Comment: Thanks, I adapted the answer following your suggestions